# Which mod in the RLcraft modpack adds the ability to pick up items by clicking on them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I tried RLcraft modpack recently, and I noticed that it has not only "physical inventory" mod, but something that lets you pick up items from the ground by clicking on them. Items wouldn't be picked up automatically.

Does anyone know which mod does this? If it isn't a mod, how can I do same thing in my unmodded Minecraft?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the mod in the modpack that does this is [ItemPhysics](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/itemphysic). This is not a vanilla feature, so you need mods in order to implement it into your game.

Comment: Well… You could in theory make a gigantic complicated commands system that does the same in Vanilla. But that's a ton of effort for not much gain.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for it, it's this mod: [Realistic Item Drops](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/realistic-item-drops).